# Angular animations not working on Firefox due to CSP (with web-animations-js in polyfills.ts)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-animations

I have issue applying Angular animations on Firefox (and Safari).
Yes I know that there are a lot of answers out there saying you can simply adding `web-animations-js` in `polyfills.ts` and it should do the trick. Unfortunately, it's not working in my case. For your context, this is the CSP policy that we're using `default-src 'self'; img-src: *`.

This is the animation code:

```
    animations: [
        trigger('toggleCommunicationPanel', [
            state('close', style({
                maxWidth: '64px',
                width: '4vw'
            })),
            state('open', style({
                width: '25vw',
                minWidth: '480px'
            })),
            transition('open=>close', animate('250ms')),
            transition('close=>open', animate('250ms'))
        ])
    ]
```

This is a chunk of `polyfills.ts`

```
/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.


/**
 * Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`
 * Only required if AnimationBuilder is used within the application and using IE/Edge or Safari.
 * Standard animation support in Angular DOES NOT require any polyfills (as of Angular 6.0).
 */
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.
```

I have configured Angular to `extract scss` into a single big `.css` file (to avoid CSP issue). Because by default, Angular CLI will not extract your styles into a stylesheet file, instead it will inject the styles into the DOM using `<style>` element, this is done for each component style. Hence, you will end up having a lot of `<style>` element in the `<head>` element. This of course violates the CSP rule above.

I've noticed that, in Chrome, IE and Edge, the css of the animation is extracted as expected, so it's working fine. However, in Firefox, it is injected using `<style>` element.

```
<style>@keyframes gen_css_kf_2 {
 0% {
  width: 492px;
  min-Width: 0px;
  max-Width: none;
  }
 100% {
  width: 4vw;
  min-Width: 0px;
  max-Width: 64px;
  }
}
</style>
```

So I suspect it is because of this, the animation will not work on Firefox.
The solution might be to change configuration so that Angular CLI will extract css for animations (even we're using Firefox or Safari).

This is the configuration for `production`, as you can see `extractCss` has been turned on.

```
"configurations": {
    "production": {
        "fileReplacements": [{
            "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
            "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }],
        "optimization": true,
        "outputHashing": "all",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "extractCss": true,
        "namedChunks": false,
        "aot": true,
        "extractLicenses": true,
        "vendorChunk": false,
        "buildOptimizer": true,
        "budgets": [{
                "type": "initial",
                "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                "maximumError": "5mb"
            },
            {
                "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                "maximumError": "10kb"
            }
        ]
    },
    "es5": {
        "tsConfig": "./tsconfig.es5.json"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the moment, I see no way of working around this issue. The only solution is to not to use Angular animation if CSP is set to prohibit inline style. Simply translating Angular animation code to css and use `ngClass` to achieve the same effect.